# Creating a dataframe with append

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, append

I'm trying to create a DataFrame with an append:

```
col_stats= ['Attribute', 'Mean', 'Var', 'Std']
stats = pd.DataFrame(columns=[col_stats])

for i in train:
    new_row = [
        i,
        train[i].mean(),
        np.var(train[i]),
        np.nanstd(train[i])
    ]
    new_row = pd.Series(new_row)
    stats = stats.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

stats
```

It works when I eliminate this line:

```
    stats = stats.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

If not, It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'
```

The 'Attribute' columns is a string (the name of the variable). The other columns (Mean, Var, Std) are numbers (integers, floats)

Why can I not use pd.df.append here?

Comment: try this: `new_row = pd.DataFrame(new_row, columns=col_stats)`

Comment: Are you really just looking for `train.describe().T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop solution `append` rows to list and use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = []
for i in train:
    new_row = [
        i,
        train[i].mean(),
        np.var(train[i]),
        np.nanstd(train[i])
    ]
    L.append(new_row)

col_stats= ['Attribute', 'Mean', 'Var', 'Std']
stats = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=col_stats)
```

**Sample**:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

L = []
for i in train:
    new_row = [
        i,
        train[i].mean(),
        np.var(train[i]),
        np.nanstd(train[i])
    ]
    L.append(new_row)

col_stats= ['Attribute', 'Mean', 'Var', 'Std']
stats = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=col_stats)

print (stats)
  Attribute      Mean       Var       Std
0         B  4.500000  0.250000  0.500000
1         C  5.500000  6.916667  2.629956
2         D  2.833333  6.138889  2.477678
```

---

```
f1 = lambda x: x.var(ddof=0)
f2 = lambda x: x.std(ddof=0)
stats = train.agg(['mean',f1, f2]).T.reset_index()
stats.columns = ['Attribute', 'Mean', 'Var', 'Std']
print (stats)
  Attribute      Mean       Var       Std
0         B  4.500000  0.250000  0.500000
1         C  5.500000  6.916667  2.629956
2         D  2.833333  6.138889  2.477678
```